Can I cancel a hotel to stay at a friends's house?
I'm an Brazilian citizen and I'll be going to Argentina next week, I booked a hotel to stay for 2 weeks but I just realized there's a chance of me staying at my friend's house (not sure) so my question is, is there a problem if I cancel my hotel booking and stay at my friend's house after I pass throught immigration?
In my mind it can lead to zero problems but I prefer to ask... I'm a brazilian and Brazil is a part of Mercosur so I don't even need a visa to visit Argentina and I can stay for 90 days with no problem in Argentina territory.
But anyway, there's a 80% chance of me staying at a hotel, I'm just asking in case my friend's house is available so I can save some money.

What is the hotel's cancellation policy?

Are you asking about trouble with the hotel, or trouble with Argentine Immigration?

I'm asking if I will have trouble with the Argentina Immigration, I'm sorry for the lack of information.

Because I can cancel the hotel without any problem, just paying a small fee.

Where do you plan on making the immigration? Generally Argentina is a no brainer for Brazilians.

If an Immigration Officer asks about your accommodation intentions (IDK how likely that is in your situation), you can just tell the truth: you have confirmed hotel accommodation for 2 weeks but may stay with a friend at xyz address for some or all of that time instead.

The official website of the Argentinian  Ministry of the Interior (https://www.argentina.gob.ar/interior/migraciones/documentacion-para-ingresar-al-pais-como-turista) simply states

Requirements:

Passport (valid), or
Identity Card (valid) or valid travel document (valid) from your country of origin, being any of the following Brazil, Bolivia, Uruguay, Paraguay, Chile, Peru, Venezuela, Ecuador and Colombia).


There is no mentioning of "proof of accommodation".
Other websites do "recommend" having or state that "you may be asked". Example (https://www.argentina.travel/en/about-argentina/news/requirements-to-travel-to-argentina-by-car-plane-cruise-ship-and-ferry)

Additionally, it is recommended to have on hand a copy of your travel itinerary, accommodation details, return ticket, and sufficient funds for your trip, as immigration authorities may request them upon entering the country.

Chances are you'll be fine. I've entered Argentina with a US passport twice in the last 3 years and was never asked for any of this.
